# Magento dynamic product price

Tags: configurable-product, price, custom

Does anyone know how to make a product with **not fixed** price?

By default the product price is $1. But it can be changed by user dragging a price product slider (the product is a donation product).

So how to implement that? How to give an ability for the user to change the product price?

I was thinking about the configurable product with attribute set but I'm not sure that it's really elegant way to do so.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362485/magento-dynamic-pricing

Comment: So you're suggesting to change a product page in the DB. But what if the same time two users would add this product into the cart? Could it cause some product price violation conflict?

Comment: No.. you are changing the getQuoteItem() which is per quote/cart and not the product

Comment: Did that work for you, should I write it up as an answer?

Comment: @R.S I think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to create a product in magento to use as a template.

Then create a observer

```
<events>
    <sales_quote_add_item>
        <observers>
            <priceupdate_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                <method>updatePrice</method>
            </priceupdate_observer>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_add_item>
</events>
```

Then in your observer method you does something like this:

```
public function updatePrice($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
    $new_price = <insert logic to check if this is the custom product and to get value from ajax>
    $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
    $quote_item->save();
}
```

(note that a user could always fake the post and change the item price)

See [Customize Magento using Event/Observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom option for that, with 100(?) options, each in 1$ steps (or maybe higher steps later).

Than you can implement a slider, write some JS to change the select box for the custom option, hide it and finished.

Comment: Is it really elegant solution if I need $10 000 maximum price? I don't think so that creating 10 000 options would be great idea.