# Send price in cart

Tags: price

i have products, product have custom options, when user check custom options price = 13.30$, need send in cart price = 26.90$ for example (little hook =)), how i can better can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to create a product in magento to use as a template.

Then create a observer

```
<events>
    <sales_quote_add_item>
        <observers>
            <priceupdate_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                <method>updatePrice</method>
            </priceupdate_observer>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_add_item>
</events>
```

Then in your observer method you does something like this:

```
public function updatePrice($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
    $new_price = <insert logic to check if this is the custom product and to get value from ajax>
    $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
    $quote_item->save();
}
```

See [Magento dynamic product price](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36987/magento-dynamic-product-price)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by event observer

```
<config>
    ...
    <frontend>
        ...
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <unique_event_name>
                        <class>{{modulename}}/observer</class>
                        <method>modifyPrice</method>
                    </unique_event_name>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        </events>
        ...
    </frontend>
    ...
</config>
```

see at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104482/programmatically-add-product-to-cart-with-price-change